# How to create export csv to sqlite db file with unknown schema

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to compare CSV files in matching pairs that are 100GB each for any differences that they contain.  I can't do in memory comparing because they are to big (obviously).  I can't do line by line comparing because data could be in different orders.  For example, line 1 in file A is line 293848292 in file B.  The schema for all of these CSV files are unknown.  If need be, we could read the first line of file A to get the column count, but this is a last resort effort, because perhaps there could just be a mismatch in the first line.  My solution was to read each into a sqlite table then do a comparison between the tables(If you have a better solution, please let me know).  Also another thing to note, we will assume there are no PKs and no Header rows.  How would one read this file of unknown schema into a sqlite table?

Yes, I have searched around stackoverflow, but all solutions I have found are for a known schema.

Comment: ... This doesn't sound like an enviable task. Are these just flat files on a regular computer?

Comment: @roganjosh This is a comparison framework that is made for small file comparison in memory.  Theoretically, no file will exceed 10MB but part of the requirements is that it handles files(CSV) of any size so they want a fall back system if for some odd reason the files don't fit in memory, even though it should never happen.  I have the in memory part working fine, but am having trouble designing the fall back system for arbitrarily large files.

Comment: If you don't know the schema, what are you comparing? If you only need to know if they are different, just caclulate a checksum.

Comment: @bitfiddler I need to know the exact differences, what is the exact value of the exact row that is different.  When the rows could be out of order

Comment: Since the previous question was answered with pandas, maybe look at [dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)? specifically for the "Dask is convenient on a laptop. It installs trivially with conda or pip and extends the size of convenient datasets from “fits in memory” to “fits on disk”." functionality

Comment: That looks promising.  I will look into that, my only concern is speed, comparing to make sure each dataframe contains each others rows, without any database functionality, I could reasonably see that taking a week to compare 2 files with 100million rows each using that approach, but I will test it out.  Thanks

Comment: I have no figures to back it up at all, but I would be extremely surprised if sqlite could do a better job than dask.

Comment: Okay, that's pleasant to here.  This sounds like a much better solution than creating a temporary sqlite db.  thanks a lot!